# Passing parameters by Postman to Eclipse-SUMO Docker image

Tags: docker, postman, sumo, postman-collection-runner

I am new to docker, and I have been asked to run a simulation via a docker image of **SUMO** (Simulation of Urban MObility) on a server on the cloud, and I should pass the simulation parameters in a JSON format file by Postman.

Everything is kind of blurry for me, also I couldn't find any doc or video in YouTube explaining such thing.

Can somebody give me an insight or any references?

Thank you very much guys.

EDIT: This is an snapshot of JSON file for parameters of simulation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoLwh.png)

Comment: what you try?. what is the question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @S.Sachith, I added a photo of postman which shows a collection file I should post/put/get to sumo container to control the simulation. In normal condition which I run SUMO in my linux machine and simulate with .osm, .net.xml and rou.xml files I can run and everything is fine. But with a dockerized SUMO and these JSON file, I don't know what should I do?